# Glyphicon Icons in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, glyphicons

I need a glyphicon icon like this :

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
```

I want to append this icon using jquery to a paragraph,based on the results obtained from ajax call.

I tried this, but its not working.

```
var icon="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle' title='Insert an appropriate value'></i>";
 $(idprop).append(icon);
```

"idprop" is an id to paragraph tag .Is this the correct way ??

Comment: why do you think it is not the correct way

Comment: for getting elements with specific id use #.
for your e.g use $("#idprop").append(icon);

Answer (score 2):

Since `"idprop" is an id to paragraph tag`. You need to use `#` to target element by `id`:

```
$('#idprop').append(icon);
```

Comment: I recommend this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer (you should use `'#id'`) but I like this way:

```
var icon = $('<i/>', {
    'class':'glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle',
    'title':'Insert an appropriate value'
 });

 $('#idprop').append(icon); // appends at last

 // Most probably you need to use prepend
 $('#idprop').prepend(icon); // appends at firstst
```